# JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog not being editable

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm writing a `JDesktopPane` application, and in a `JInternalFrame`, I've got a `JEditorPane` with a webpage open (yes, I'm aware of the crappy abilities of `JEditorPane` with the net, don't scold).

I have a way for the user to input a page they would like to visit, but when I call `JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(this, "What page would you like to visit?")` the text field is not editable. This problem has occurred for me both in Java 6 and Java 7.

EDIT: 
Here's the constructor of my class

```
public Internet() {
    super("Internet", true, true, true, true);
    setSize(500, 400);
    try {
        pane = new JEditorPane(new URL("http://www.vetrustech.tk"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentPane(pane);
    bar = new JMenuBar();
    page = new JMenu("Page");
    enterPage = new JMenuItem("Enter a page");
    bar.add(page);
    page.add(enterPage);

    setJMenuBar(bar);

    enterPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            loadPage();
        }
    });
```

and here's the method for loading the page

```
private void loadPage() {
    String s = JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(this,
            "What page are you visiting?");
    if (s == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (s.equals("")) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        URL u = new URL(s);
        pane.setPage(u);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so we can see what you are doing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Noted, and added.

Comment: Hm, that's not an [sscce](http://sscce.org). I'm not sure if I can help. Maybe @Mad can. The only suggestion I'd have would be to get the URL on a background thread in a SwingWorker.

Comment: Alright. I'm still a tad bit new to this community. Thanks.

Comment: The URL processing is irrelevant to your question. The question is about the text field not being editable. So create a SSCCE that displays the popup when using a JDesktop pane.

Comment: All I was doing was JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(this, "Message here..") as stated in the question above.

Comment: I still don't see a SSCCE! Don't tell us what you are doing. Post the code that proves what you are doing.

Comment: @TheNerdyCoder I've written a quick test and I have no issues.  There must be something about the way you instaniating the option pane that you're not showing.  A quick example that demonstrates the problem is critical if you want a quick answer to your problems

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reason why a suited SSCCE is so important...

This works....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Internet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Internet();
    }

    public Internet() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane();
                final JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame("Help", true, true, true, true);
                inf.setSize(200, 200);
                inf.setVisible(true);
                dp.add(inf);

                JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(inf, "Hit me");
                    }
                });
                inf.add(btn);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(dp);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This suggests that you are doing something else in your code that we're not seeing.

Comment: Well, you pretty much summed up what I'm doing besides a quick UIManager.put("PopupMenuUI", "net.my.thing.ShadowMenuUI"); // not real package name

I have a ShadowMenuUI I like to use, but otherwise you've summed up what I'm doing.

Comment: Okay, so my example works, have you tried removing the `UIManager.put("PopupMenuUI", "net.my.thing.ShadowMenuUI");` to see if that is affecting it?

Comment: Hold that thought. I've found my error. I forgot to mention that instead of using JFrame I was using JWindow, and I had called GraphicsConfiguration g = getGraphicsConfiguration();
setUndecorated(true);
  
g.getDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);

I changed it to JFrame, and removed the fullScreenWindow part, and now it works.

Comment: Now do you understand why a SSCCE is sooooo important. Do you realize how much of our time you wasted!!!@!! because you made a silly mistake. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Well, I'm not either. I'm sorry that I've waisted time, but we've learned something from this. JWindow and JFrame are a little weird when working with some swing components.

Comment: @TheNerdyCoder Actually, I  think you'll find it's a full screen issue, doesn't seem to like `JDesktop` for some reason

Comment: @MadProgrammer Perhaps we should report this as a bug.

Comment: `Well, I'm not either.` Exactly. and that is why a SSCCE should be posted because you can't possibly remember to give us all the details in a verbal description. So start with something simple. If it works then you compare the code to your real code to see what is different.

Comment: Don't know about full screen, but this is definitely known behaviour with a JWindow. A JWindow is not focusable when you just create the window using `new JWindow();` You can click buttons but that is about it. If you want text fields on a JWindow then you need to use `new JWindow(frame);` where frame is a visible JFrame. So I'm guessing that because the dialog parent is a non-focusable window, the dialog is non focusable as well. P.S. Think you will get a thank you for your help?

Comment: @camickr An up-vote would have at least been nice :( - Didn't know that about `JWindow`, presumably a full screen window is using the same functionality as `JWindow`

Comment: @camickr Had a quick play around with Full Screen, a `JWindow` has the same problems as you described, but if you base it on a undecorated `JFrame` it seems to work okay.  Still can't show a modal dialog though

Comment: Yes, undecorated JFrame is generally better than a JWindow when you need components to be focusable. I've never really understood when you would use a JWindow. It really seems to only be useful for displaying a label with an image. Something like a splash screen. I know its also use by popup menus when the menus are outside the bounds of the frame.

Comment: @camickr That at least now explains `JFrame#setUndecorated` for me